# AMD AGESA is a part of EFI?

Tags: bios

When using AMD AGESA, does it mean the system didn't need to use EFI?

AMD AGESA is another type of EFI?

or AMD AGESA is a part of firmware in EFI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AGESA is an integral part of UEFI firmware which is responsible for low level CPU management (operating frequencies, voltages and TDP/TTP) and IO management (USB, PCI-E, etc).

Without AGESA your system won't boot/start/work. UEFI firmware has many components, AGESA is one of them. It doesn't replace anything, it just is.